# How can I use complex analysis to compute the integral of $\int_0^\infty \frac{x^\alpha}{1 + (kx)^\beta} dx$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals, contour-integration

How can I use complex analysis to compute the integral of

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^\alpha}{1 + (kx)^\beta} dx$$

I would like to see how to do it using keyhole integration or some other method.

Comment: Normally, I'd avoid contours with $x=\frac1k\tan^{2/\beta}t$.

Comment: The result is $$\frac{\pi}{\beta\cdot k^{\alpha+1}\cdot\sin{(\pi(\alpha+1)/\beta)}}$$by applying some basic results regarding the Beta function.

Comment: What are the restrictions on the parameters?

Comment: @PeterForeman Could you show me step by step how to do that. I am not familiar with the Beta function